# Can't make remote desktop connection on Windows 2008 server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, firewall

I have two servers in my local LAN. One with Windows 2003 and one with Windows 2008 server.
Also I have a static IP assigned to My ADSL modem. In my modem control panel I defined some virtual server to access to my Local server from the Internet. I have no problem accessing the windows 2003 server but I can't connect to the windows 2008 server. I opened All port in windows 2008 server even turned off the firewall, but I don't know whats wrong. When I check my IP with port scan it shows the ports that assigned to windows 2008 as filtered.

I can remote desktop to my server via local LAN but via Internet and out of my office I can't.

Comment: Sounds like your NAT isn't setup correctly. If you only have 1 IP address, you'll need to redirect one of your ports (which ever you want) to redirect to port 3389 on your Windows 2008 Server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error when attempting to connect? It would be a good idea to provide the exact text from the error message if this is the case.

I'd suggest looking at this [Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2477023) and working your way through the steps if you haven't already.

The article does specify server 2003, but I think most (if not all), applies to server 2008.